# How to check if org entry is in an ordered list

Tags: org-mode

Is there an existing function that indicates if an org entry is contained in an ordered list?

I am writing a hook that changes the next item in a list from TODO to NEXT.  I only want the entry to change when it is in an ordered list.  In the snippet below, changing Task A of A to DONE will trigger Task B of A to change its todo tag to NEXT.  However, changing Task A of B will not trigger Task B of B to change its todo tag.

```
* TODO Project A
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ORDERED: t
  :END:
  ** NEXT Task A of A
  ** TODO Task B of A
* TODO Project B
  ** NEXT Task A of B
  ** TODO Task B of B
```

Is there a function that will tell me that Task B of A is in an ordered list when point is on Task B of A?

Answer (score 1):

> Function: org-entry-get pom property &optional inherit
>
> Get value of PROPERTY for entry at point-or-marker POM.
>
> By default, this only looks at properties defined locally in the entry.
>
> If INHERIT is non-nil and the entry does not have the property, then also check higher levels of the hierarchy.
>
> If INHERIT is the symbol selective, use inheritance if and only if the setting of org-use-property-inheritance >selects PROPERTY for inheritance.

https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-property-API.html

org-entry-get does the trick as long as the optional property inherit is set